# Jboss shows error with datasource on startup

Tags: postgresql, servlets, jboss

On starting jboss I am getting the following error :

```
--- MBEANS THAT ARE THE ROOT CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM ---
ObjectName: jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=DefaultDS
  State: NOTYETINSTALLED
  Depends On Me:
    jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService,persistencePolicy=database
    jboss:service=KeyGeneratorFactory,type=HiLo
    jboss.mq:service=StateManager
    jboss.mq:service=PersistenceManager
```

And for all database connections in the servlet I get the following exception :

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password a
uthentication failed for user "poll"
```

It was working fine and all of a sudden I started getting these errors. My password is correct. I even tried changing the password and then tried again it showed the same exception. What is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DefaultDS` data source is what the name suggests; the default datasource. It ships with JBoss and is configured to use the Hypersonic (ie in-memory) database. JBoss uses the `DefaultDS` datasource to read/write internal queues, timed events, etc

Check the file `../conf/standardjbosscmp-jdbc.xml` to see what you've got configured for the `DefaultDS` datasource. It sounds like you've edited that file unintentionally. Unless you need to persist internal queues etc across boots, just leave it as shipped using Hypersonic.

See the [JBoss doc](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/getting_started/v4/html/cmp.html) for more.